# Instance method 'application(application:handleOpenURL:)' nearly matches optional requirement

Tags: ios, swift, warnings, appdelegate

I am getting warning for below method,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {

    print("URL openning: \(String(describing: url.absoluteString))")
    os_log("URL openning:: %{public}s", url.absoluteString!)

    return true
}
```

Warning:

> Instance method 'application(application:handleOpenURL:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'application(_:handleOpen:)' of protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

Suggestion:

> Make 'application(application:handleOpenURL:)' private to silence this warning

However, i am in doubt whether that function should be private or not because that will be triggered by iOS fw itself when a oAuth callback is fired.

**Why iOS suggesting to be private?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implementing a function from `UIApplicationDelegate` and you misspelled the function signature, which makes your function very similar to the one from the protocol, but not exactly - that's why the compiler is complaining.

You're missing the underscore `_` - `application` parameter doesn't have a label when calling the function:

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleOpen url: URL) -> Bool
```

Secondly, you shouldn't be using that function anyway since it has been deprecated in iOS 10. Use

```
optional func application(_ app: UIApplication, 
                       open url: URL, 
                        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

instead